# REGEX extract information from EDGAR SC-13 form

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, finance, edgar

I am trying to extract information from the latest [SEC EDGAR Schedule 13 forms](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&CIK=&type=SC%2013&owner=include&count=40&action=getcurrent) filings.

Link of the filing as an example:

1) [Saba Capital_27-Dec-2019_SC13](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058239/000106299319004848/formsc13da.htm)

The information I am trying to extract (and the parts of the filing with the information)

1) Names of reporting persons: *Saba Capital Management, L.P.*

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 0pt;">NAME OF REPORTING PERSON</p>
<p style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-left: 18pt;">Saba Capital Management GP, LLC<br><br/>
```

2) Name of issuer : *WESTERN ASSET HIGH INCOME FUND II INC*

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><b><font size="5"><u>WESTERN ASSET HIGH INCOME FUND II INC.</u></font><u><br/></u>(Name of Issuer)</b>
```

3) CUSIP Number: *95766J102* (managed to get)

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><b><u>95766J102<br/></u>(CUSIP Number)</b>
```

4) Percentage of class represented by amount : *11.3%* (managed to get)

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 0pt;">PERCENT OF CLASS REPRESENTED BY AMOUNT IN ROW (11)</p>
<p style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-left: 18pt;">11.3%<br><br/>
```

5) Date of Event Which requires filing of this statement: *December 24, 2019*

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><b><u>December 24, 2019<br/></u>(Date of Event Which Requires Filing of This Statement)</b>
```

.

```
import requests 
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058239/000106299319004848/formsc13da.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'xml')

## get CUSIP number
CUSIP = re.findall(r'[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9*@#]{3}[0-9]', soup.text)

### get % 
regex = r"(?<=PERCENT OF CLASS|Percent of class)(.*)(?=%)"
percent = re.findall(r'\d+.\d+', re.search(regex, soup.text, re.DOTALL).group().split('%')[0])
```

How can I extract the 5 pieces of information from the filing? Thanks in advance

Comment: CUSIP = `soup.select("body > document > type > sequence > filename > description > text > p:nth-child(9) > b > u")get_text()`

Comment: kindly confirm if all items in sames positions in case if you will apply the code on multiple pages.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for html under any circumstances (search around to see why). The easiest way to do it is with xpath, which would require using lxml instead of beautifulsoup. I you're are interested, I can post an answer.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I dont think all the items are in the same position. Yes, I want to apply it to other pages

Comment: @JackFleeting yes, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following **Code** to get all the values.Using `find`() and css selector `select_one`()

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058239/000106299319004848/formsc13da.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
NameReportingperson=soup.find('p', text=re.compile('NAME OF REPORTING PERSON')).find_next('p').text.strip()
print(NameReportingperson)
NameOftheIssuer=soup.select_one('p:nth-child(7) > b u').text.strip()
print(NameOftheIssuer)
CUSIP=soup.select_one("p:nth-child(9) > b > u").text.strip()
print(CUSIP)
percentage=soup.find('p', text=re.compile('PERCENT OF CLASS REPRESENTED BY AMOUNT IN ROW')).find_next('p').text.strip()
print(percentage)
Dateof=soup.select_one("p:nth-child(11) > b > u").text.strip()
print(Dateof)
```

**Output**:

```
Saba Capital Management, L.P.
WESTERN ASSET HIGH INCOME FUND II INC.
95766J102
11.3%
December 24, 2019
```

---

**UPDATED**

---

If you don't want to use position then try below one.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058239/000106299319004848/formsc13da.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
NameReportingperson=soup.find('p', text=re.compile('NAME OF REPORTING PERSON')).find_next('p').text.strip()
print(NameReportingperson)
NameOftheIssuer=soup.select_one('p:contains(Issuer)').find_next('u').text.strip()
print(NameOftheIssuer)
CUSIP=soup.select_one('p:contains(CUSIP)').find_next('u').text.strip()
print(CUSIP)
percentage=soup.find('p', text=re.compile('PERCENT OF CLASS REPRESENTED BY AMOUNT IN ROW')).find_next('p').text.strip()
print(percentage)
Dateof=soup.select_one('p:contains(Event)').find_next('u').text.strip()
print(Dateof)
```

**Output**:

```
Saba Capital Management, L.P.
WESTERN ASSET HIGH INCOME FUND II INC.
95766J102
11.3%
December 24, 2019
```

**Update 2:**

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058239/000106299319004848/formsc13da.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
NameReportingperson=soup.find('p', text=re.compile('NAME OF REPORTING PERSON')).find_next('p').text.strip()
print(NameReportingperson)
NameOftheIssuer=soup.select_one('p:nth-of-type(7) > b u').text.strip()
print(NameOftheIssuer)
CUSIP=soup.select_one("p:nth-of-type(9) > b > u").text.strip()
print(CUSIP)
percentage=soup.find('p', text=re.compile('PERCENT OF CLASS REPRESENTED BY AMOUNT IN ROW')).find_next('p').text.strip()
print(percentage)
Dateof=soup.select_one("p:nth-of-type(11) > b > u").text.strip()
print(Dateof)
```

Comment: I can't get the soup.select_one for the name of issuer, CUSIP and Date to work. If the position of the items change, these 3 may not work right ?

Comment: Yes if the position of the item change you cannot get that.

Comment: NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-846246224fc2> in <module>()
----> 9 NameOftheIssuer=soup.select_one('p:contains(Issuer)').find_next('u').text.strip()
  
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bs4/element.py in select(self, selector, _candidate_generator, limit)
   1526                 else:
   1527                     raise NotImplementedError(
-> 1528                         'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of

NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: Ok got your problem replace nth-child to nth-of-type

Comment: how should i change it ?

Comment: @Lko : I would suggest use the updated code where you don't need to use position.Have you tried the answer under updated option.

Comment: yes, I used the updated code and got the error above

Comment: Dont know why you are getting error.Can you try Update 2 option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205082/discussion-between-lko-and-kunduk).

Comment: @KunduK is there a way to make the 
 "Issuer" in this soup.select_one('p:contains(Issuer)')  less case sensitive so that it searches for ['Issuer', 'ISSUER', 'issuer'] ?

Comment: @KunduK is there a way to search for multiple tags at the same time <p> <div> <tr> because the document formating may be different

Answer (score 0):

Using lxml, it should work this way:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058239/000106299319004848/formsc13da.htm'
source = requests.get(url)

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(source.text)
name = doc.xpath('//p[text()="NAME OF REPORTING PERSON"]/following-sibling::p/text()')[0]
issuer = doc.xpath('//p[contains(text(),"(Name of Issuer)")]//u/text()')[0]
cusip = doc.xpath('//p[contains(text(),"(CUSIP Number)")]//u/text()')[0]
perc = doc.xpath('//p[contains(text(),"PERCENT OF CLASS REPRESENTED")]/following-sibling::p/text()')[0]
event = doc.xpath('//p[contains(text(),"(Date of Event Which Requires")]//u/text()')[0]
```

Output:

```
Saba Capital Management, L.P.
WESTERN ASSET HIGH INCOME FUND II INC.
95766J102
11.3%
December 24, 2019
```

Comment: this works on this page. Can you explain how can i apply to other pages (from the same type of filing) example: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1061983/000089914019000648/p32629470a.htm

Comment: @Lko - Unfortunately, that's exactly one of the main problems with parsing EDGAR filings. The SEC doesn't require a uniform edgarization method, so each filer edgarizes its filings (or the edgarization service provider does) differently. In many cases, filings from the same filer use the same edgarization format, but you still have to do some manual inspection of the filing to figure out where things hide...

Comment: ic, can you explain '//u/text()' and '/following-sibling::p/text()' or any resources that i can find out more ?

Comment: @Lko - There's quite a lot of info about xpath, though it may take a while to grasp. Good place to start is: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp